# Create RStudio connection that uses environment variables as defaults

Tags: r, google-bigquery, rstudio, bigrquery

I am trying to add connection snippet to the bigrquery package based on this documentation:

https://db.rstudio.com/advanced/snippets/

I would like to default project name to a env var like this:

```
library(bigrquery)
con <-  dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = "${1:Project=Sys.getenv('BIGQUERY_PROJECT')}"
)
```

Unfortunately this does not work, as `Sys.getenv('BIGQUERY_PROJECT')` is not evaluated.

**UPDATE**
e.g. for @Jozef's example I get the following code generated:

```
library(bigrquery)
con <-  dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = "`r eval({Sys.getenv('BIGQUERY_PROJECT'))`"
)
```

**UPDDATE 2**

This sort of works, but does not look good:

```
library(bigrquery)
con <-  dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = paste0("${1:Project=", Sys.getenv("BIGQUERY_PROJECT"), "}")
)
```

Comment: Can you Analyse your problem using debug()? And what is the link to snippets?

Comment: how can I use `debug` for this?

Comment: Debug(bigrquery::dbConnect). See ??Debug.

Comment: `bigrquery::dbConnect` works as expected, I cannot find a way to inject environment variable into the connection snippet

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can use `r eval({ })` in back-ticks if I understand your purpose correctly.

Example with the 'USER' environment variable:

```
snippet envvar
    library(bigrquery)
    con <-  dbConnect(
        bigquery(),
        project = "${1:Project=`r eval({Sys.getenv('USER')})`}"
    )
```

Will do this for my user (jozef) when triggered:

[image]

Also, I [wrote a post with more examples](https://jozef.io/r906-rstudio-snippets) of advanced snippet use.